# How can I reset data to default in Bootstrap modal using AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

How can I reset data to default in Bootstrap modal using AngularJS?
This is how am I trying to do:

```
$scope.initial = [
    {
      name: 'nam_fruit',
      price: 0
    }];

    $scope.reset = function(){
    $scope.dataFruit = $scope.initial;  
  }
```

But it doesn't work. Fields still have old data. Check my fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/q69yckt1/

Comment: Tip if you are not using controllerAs syntax https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#style-y030 see also y031, y032

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assigning an array as initial model. just remove `[]` and that should work:

```
$scope.initial =
{
  name: 'nam_fruit',
  price: 0
};

$scope.reset = function(){
  $scope.dataFruit = angular.copy($scope.initial);  
}
```

as devqon mentioned in his comment you should also create a copy of `$scope.initial` as its just a reference copy if you just use `$scope.dataFruit = $scope.initial;`.

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/hsh85/q69yckt1/3/) is the working fiddle.

Comment: Also note that he just creates a reference copy, so the `$scope.initial` will change if he changes `$scope.dataFruit`. Instead do something like `$scope.dataFruit = angular.copy($scope.initial);`

Comment: @DiPix, `ng-lick="reset()"` is misspelled

Answer (score 0):

```
var vm = this;
//(like a private field)
var initial_is_editable = true;
vm.initial = [{
  name: 'nam_fruit',
  price: 0
},{
  name: 'nam_fruit',
  price: 0
}];

function reset(reset_modal_index){
  if(initial_is_editable){
    vm.initial[reset_modal_index].name = "default_name"; 
    vm.initial[reset_modal_index].price= "default_price"; 
  }
  vm.dataFruit[reset_modal_index] = vm.initial[reset_modal_index];
}
```

If I understand correctly: We have set of dataFruit modals and we are reseting data of chosen one to initial values.